# MariaDB lost database MYSQL after 1-2 days

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a big problem and i tried to fix this since weeks.
After 1-2 days i lost the database "mysql" in MariaDB (Server version: 10.5.12-MariaDB MariaDB package) running on OpenSuSe Leap 15.3.
Only the client database (but without more tables) and the database "information_shema" exists.
Database "mysql" not more exists.
I need to reinstall the database server, set all the passwords, etc., import the database from a backup and all works fine, but after one day, more ore less, the database "mysql" is not more.
Also the folder "/var/lib/mysql" contains only the folder of my clients database and of "information_shema".
Only the user "root" have access to the database server and only with password.
Every day i run a backup of the databases, but i have now no more idea how this is posible.
I changed all passwords for the reason it is not hacked, but always the same result.
Have someone an idea?
Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sounds like something or someone on your server is deleting `/var/lib/mysql/mysql`. MariaDB won't do this spontaneously.

Comment: If the database is used by a web server, then confirm that it's not using the `root` SQL account and search your web server logs for something that looks like a SQL injection 

Comment: Thanks a lot@all!

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the mysql database doesn't spontaneously disappear from MariaDB. Check for SQL injection in your logs. As best practice however, I recommend you to create a user specifically for the application connecting to the database.

`CREATE USER appuser IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`

If the application is running on the same machine, you can restrict external access like so:

`CREATE USER appuser@localhost;`

Then, grant the application user access only to the application database(s).

`GRANT ALL ON app_database.* to appuser;`

Or if you created the user with the host database:

`GRANT ALL ON app_database.* to appuser@localhost;`

Worst case scenario now is that an SQL injection will only expose the application database, not the server's user passwords. As always, remember [little Bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).